# Append "node" to tab menu link

Tags: views

I have a view that display members for a group. The path for this view is set as node/%/members. When I go to group page, the menu works fine:

[image: Link in first page works]

[image: When I enter in Members]

[image: Link to Menus are: "node/nid/node/nid" repeats the node/nid]

[image: Can't find the page, because the link needs to be: node/nid/group-forum]

I can't find anyway to change these links.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with the view. The url paths used for your tabs are using relative URLs (e.g. "node/$nid/group-forum") you need use absolute URLs (e.g. "/node/$nid/group-forum").

```
<ul class="tabs--primary nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="node/1147" title="View"><i class="fa "></i>View</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="node/1147/group-forum" title="Forum"><i class="fa "></i>Forum</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="node/1147/members" title="Members"><i class="fa "></i>Members</a></li>
</ul>
```

You need to check the rendering logic in your theme templates to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I change to the absolute path? Because I am using this path in my view: http://v2.globalnoticeboard.com/node/%/group-forum

Comment: I've updated the answer to elaborate further, you need to check the render logic of your primary tab links.